# all() function is not working as expected

Tags: r

I have a vector and I want to be sure that all its values are between 1800 and 900

All the values are integer.

I did this:

```
areThereOutRangedTimeValues <- function (time){
  valuesGreaterThan <- time > 1800
  if(all(valuesGreaterThan) == FALSE){
  valuesLessThan <- time< 900
  if(all(valuesLessThan) == FALSE){
    return (FALSE)
  }
  else
  {
    return (TRUE)
  }
  }else{
    return (TRUE)
  }
}
```

I don't know why when I test it like this:

```
areThereOutRangedTimeValues(c(1:1801))
```

The answer is `FALSE`, even though it should have been `TRUE`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The issue is

```
all(valuesGreaterThan) == FALSE
```

which should really be (note the parentheses)

```
all(valuesGreaterThan == FALSE)
```

Same for valuesLessThan

However, this seems like a very involved way of doing

```
any(time<900 | time>1800)
```

Comment: Thank you, i will accept your answer when the system allows

Answer (score 1):

Building on the answer by nico. If you want a function:

```
OutRanged <- function(time) {
  any(time < 900 | time > 1800)
}

OutRanged(1:1801)
[1] TRUE
```

You can also make it more useful by being able to change the range if wanted.

```
OutRanged <- function(time, lower=900, upper=1800) {
  any(time < lower | time > upper)
}
```

So now you can still do the same test:

```
OutRanged(1:1801)
[1] TRUE
```

Or you can add a different upper or lower bound to the range:

```
OutRanged(1:1801, 0, 1801)
[1] FALSE
```